# Parsing complextype result in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have the following response from a SOAP server

```
<result>VGhpcyBpcyBub3QgdGhlIHJvYm90IHlvdSBhcmUgbG9va2luZyBmb3I=</result>
```

But I don't know how to parse the result, supposedly there's information in there, the WSDL document establish the following:

```
<s:element name="some_response">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="result">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Is there a way to parse the xml response into an object? I'm using simple_xml... for parsing the response.

Answer (score 1):

That result is base64 encoded.

```
echo base64_decode('VGhpcyBpcyBub3QgdGhlIHJvYm90IHlvdSBhcmUgbG9va2luZyBmb3I=');
```

outputs:

```
This is not the robot you are looking for
```